# Undef ref to vtable in constructor and destructor in non-Q

Tags: inheritance, vtable, virtual-destructor

I've got a base class, GameObject, which currently parents Camera and SolidObject. SolidObject parents Player and GameMap. For some reason I'm only getting undefined references to vtable in the constructor and destructor of GameMap. Here's the code (I won't include Camera or Player). NOTE: GameObject and SolidObject are in World.h because they are small and need to be connected. I will only include stuff related to those classes and GameMap.

I switched the inheritance so GameMap inherits from GameObject instead of SolidObject, but it still causes the same error.

World.h

```
class GameObject
{
public:
    World* parent;
    unsigned int objID;

    virtual void step();
};

class SolidObject : public GameObject
{
public:
    float xpos, ypos, zpos;
    float xrot, yrot, zrot;
};
```

World.cpp

```
void GameObject::step()
{

}
```

GameMap.h

```
class GameMap : public GameObject
{
private:
    WFOBJ model;

public:
    GameMap(World* world, char* modelFile, char* textureFile);
    ~GameMap();

    void step();
    void setModel();
};
```

GameMap.cpp

```
void step()
{

}

GameMap::GameMap(World* world, char* modelFile, char* textureFile)
{
    model.loadFile(modelFile, textureFile);

    objID = world->addObject(this);
    parent = world;
}

GameMap::~GameMap()
{
    parent->removeObject(objID);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at `step()`'s definition in GameMap.cpp - it's missing the class name. It should have been declared as `void GameMap::step()`. The error should actually have mentioned that `step`'s definition cannot be found, but [as explained in the great C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/strange-inheritance.html#faq-23.10), you might get this error instead.